# Is the Cauchy's Theorem valid for a path with multiple points?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f$ be analytic in a finite simply-connected region $\mathcal{R}$ described by the inside of a closed curve $C$ (that can contain multiple points) and on its boundary $C$. Then

$$ \oint_C f \overset{?}{=} 0$$

Intuitively the Cauchy's Theoreom is also valid for path with multiple point because a closed path with multiple points can be chopped in different regions (as many as parts of the path there are between a multiple point and the next one) and in each part the Cauchy's Theorem can be applied individually. So, if the theorem applies for each region, then the theorem applies for the entire path. A good example is the Lemniscata, where the theorem is obviously satisfied.

Any help with the mathematical proof?

Comment: If the region is simply-connected then the integral is zero for arbitrary closed curves, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem

Comment: In the second line it says "for any simply closed contour". The curve $C$ is said to be simple (also called a Jordan curve) if the curve never crosses itself (except possibly at its endpoints).

Comment: Check the section “Formulation on Simply Connected Regions”

Comment: Here it says that $\gamma$ is a smooth closed curve. But $\gamma$ is a smooth curve if $z(t)$ is a one-to-one function on $[a, b]$.

Comment: No, “smooth” (as I know it) does *not* mean injective. It means that $z(t)$ is sufficiently differentiable (usually piecewise $C_1$).

Comment: I used to think that, but look that website [link](https://sites.oxy.edu/ron/math/312/14/ws/17.pdf) on page 2/4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136256/discussion-between-martin-r-and-spectree).